# Setup "open files" limit in Linux per user. Cannot setup more than 1024

Tags: linux, centos, limits, ulimit

I try to increase open file limit for certain user on CentOS 5.5 Linux.
I added a new line to /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
seed     hard    nofile          10240
```

Then do test:

```
runuser -s /bin/bash - seed -c "ulimit -S -c 0>/dev/null 2>&1; ulimit -a"
0
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 8185
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

And as you can see - open file limit is still 1024.
If I set up the limit as 1000, it will be applied. So, I cannot setup the limit more than 1024.

How can I do that?? I need to set up the settings only for 1 user, not system-wide.

Comment: 1024 is a lot of open files...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx

Comment: @Chris Nava, That is nice in theory, but there are many services that will not reliably operate given that limit.  Also 1024 isn't an OS limit is a resource limit placed on accounts.

Comment: 1024 isn't a lot of open file nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect `runuser` doesn't go through PAM's "login" process that applies limits.conf, or maybe pam_limits.so is disabled.  In Debian, at least, `/etc/pam.d/su` has pam_limits.so commented out so that the limits are inherited from the user running su.

Comment: [root@seedbox01 ~]# cat /etc/passwd | grep seed
seed:x:501:501::/home/seed:/bin/bash

Comment: [root@seedbox01 ~]# cat /etc/pam.d/runuser
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
session         optional        pam_keyinit.so revoke
session         required        pam_limits.so
session         required        pam_unix.so

Comment: This is definitely the reason. I've deleted my answer as you were first :).

Answer (score 1):

To increase open file limit for certain user on CentOS 5.5 Linux:

1 - in file '/etc/security/limits.conf' add:
 - http://gerardnico.com/wiki/linux/limits.conf

```
...
# seed osuser - extended max number of open files
seed    hard    nofile    10240

# End of file
```

2 - in file '**/etc/profile**' or in '**/home/seed/.bash_profile**' add:

```
if [ $USER = "seed" ]; then
        ulimit -n 10240
fi
```

Comment: Suggestion #1 did not helped me, but #2 - yes.

Answer (score 1):

On linux systems, there are three places where file limits are set, each independent of the other:

1. the kernel, as in /proc/sys/fs/file-max, controlled via sysctl fs.filemax or /etc/sysctl.conf
2. the ulimit in the shell, as controlled by ulimit -n
3. PAM, as set via /etc/security/limits.conf

The number that takes precedence and actually determines the limit on your processes is whatever is the LEAST of the above three.

Comment: Thanks! I raise all three and yet am stuck... https://forum.hestiacp.com/t/too-many-open-files-despite-config-adjustments/8858/38

Answer (score 0):

Using "ulimit -a" you see the soft limit, 1024 in redhat 5.8 is the default soft limit

```
vim /etc/security/limits.conf
user01  soft    nofile  1024
user01  hard    nofile  2048

ulimit -Sn
1024
ulimit -Hn
2048
```

reading proc

```
grep "Max open files" /proc/$$/limits
Max open files            1024                 2048                 files
```