# How do I increase the open file limit on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, ulimit, limits

I am using CentOS 7. I found out that the current value can be seen using `$ ulimit -a` (look for open files).

Or just `$ ulimit -n`

Then I try to edit these limits by editing the file at

```
$ vim /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and adding these two lines:

```
soft nofile 999999
hard nofile 999999
```

And after doing a quick reboot and checking if something has happened

```
$ ulimit -n
```

It is still the same, I get 1024 as output.

How do I change this value and make it persist after a reboot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup "open files" limit in Linux per user. Cannot setup more than 1024](http://serverfault.com/questions/195288/setup-open-files-limit-in-linux-per-user-cannot-setup-more-than-1024)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the user part at the start, and the wrong way around, should be:

```
* soft nproc 65535
* hard nproc 65535
* soft nofile 65535
* hard nofile 65535
```